# Swing Java-sqlLite relative path connection

Tags: java, sqlite, connection

I am working on a simple java app which is using a .sqlite database. The problem is that I don't know where to put the database in the MyProject/ folder and how to make a relative connection path, such that I can use it after I wrap the project into an .exe file. Any suggestions?

This is how I do it now. I have the following path MyProject/resource/EmployeesDatabase.sqlite

```
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:resource\\EmployeesDatabase.sqlite");
```

Comment: In java, it's going to be a .jar, not a .exe ;)

Comment: Yes, it is. And how do I include the database in the file?

Comment: See [include SQLite database in executable Jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019974/include-sqlite-database-in-executable-jar).