# setting url SQLite and java

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm working on  java swing app which uses SQLite database.

The app works fine on my device, I now want to distribute the app- how do I set the url in the connection statement so that it works on all devices?

My current statement is:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
     "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Pankaj4011\\Desktop\\login\\admin.sqlite" );
```

On another device it shows this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException:path to 
    C:\\Users\\Pankaj4011\\Desktop\\login\\admin.sqlite : 
    c:\Users \Pankaj4011 does not exist`
```

Comment: Uri's aren't similar in all computers.

Comment: Read this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019974/how-to-include-sqlite-database-in-executable-jar). It should help you.