# JDBC Connection to SQLite database doesn't work when running jar

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

So i'm having a program that uses an SQLite database called `scheduling.db`. it is located in the directory `src/resources`. I create a connection object using the following code:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/resources/scheduling.db");
```

This works fine in my compiler (IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5 Ultimate Edition), but when I build a .jar file from my project and i run it (in Windows 10) gives me the following error:

```
path to 'src/resources/scheduling.db': 'C:\...\Scheduling_v5_jar\src' does not exist
```

I thought it was because of the forward slashes or something but nothing really helped, I have not tested it on Linux yet. I'm using the JDBC library `sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar`

thanks in advance!

Comment: When your database file is in a jar it needs to be accessed as a resource, not a file. Check the answer here for information on how your connection URI needs to change. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019974/how-to-include-sqlite-database-in-executable-jar

Comment: The problem is that the file system isn't available to the app that way when you package and run it as an executable JAR.

Comment: Using this url did the trick! jdbc:sqlite::resource:resources/scheduling.db, thanks!!