# java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver on javaFX Application

Tags: java, database, sqlite, javafx

I am trying to upload and retrieve an image from sqlite database.

It has been working until I have changed the jar file from `sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1` to `sqlite-jdbc-3.6.14.1`. The reason why i have changed it is because of the executable jar.The executable jar file was saying -no table  users.

Then I browse and get some helpful content from [How to include SQLite database in executable Jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019974/how-to-include-sqlite-database-in-executable-jar) but now I come up with another problem which I have specified it above.
the data type of the image is BLOB.

my code to upload and insert an image is as below:

**Inserting:**

```
Connection con = AccountSettingController.getCon();
String sql = "update settings set title =? ,image =?";

try {
   ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

   fis = new FileInputStream(file);

   ps.setString(1, nm);
   ps.setBinaryStream(2, (InputStream) fis, (int) file.length());
   int x = ps.executeUpdate();

   if (x > 0) {
      Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
      alert.setTitle("updating system settings");
      alert.setHeaderText(null);
      alert.setContentText("System setting successfully updated");
      alert.showAndWait();
      } else {

      syserrorl.setText("something went wrong");
      }

   } catch (SQLException  | FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
   }
```

**Retrieving:**

```
String sq = "select * from settings";
handler = DatabaseHandler.getInstance();

ResultSet result = handler.executeQuery(sq);

String title = null;

while (result.next()) {
    title = result.getString("title");
}

InputStream is = result.getBinaryStream("image");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new  File("photo.jpg"));

byte[] content = new byte[1024];
int size = 0;

while ((size = is.read(content)) != -1) {
     os.write(content, 0, size);
}

name.setText(title);

}
System.out.println(title);
image = new Image("file:photo.jpg", imgview.getFitWidth(), 
imgview.getFitHeight(), true, true);
imgview.setImage(image);
```

Thanks for your time and considerations!

Comment: Post the entire error message and stack trace you are getting. You don't need to downgrade your SQLite JDBC driver because a different version was indicated in the _Stack Overflow_ question you provided a link to in your question. That question is seven years old. I'm guessing that the older JDBC driver probably does not support BLOB data type. I suggest you do as they say in that question but use the most up-to-date JDBC driver instead of the one indicated in that **old** question.

Comment: Abra,Thanks for your suggestion.I have tried it with another way with the up-to-date JDBC driver and works fine.